# Cannot disable Hardware acceleration using Selenium in c#

Tags: c#, .net, selenium-webdriver

I am using Selenium library in c# to open and control Chrome. When the chrome is opened (I am testing playback events), I take screenshots of the monitor and process them to determine when certain event occurred. The problem is that due to hardware-acceleration (i suppose that is the problem), the printscreens come back empty (black). How can I force the chrome opened by Selenium in my code to have hardware-acceleration disabled?

I have tried disabling the hardware-acceleration in chrome itself (in settings and in chrome://flags), but Selenium opens chrome with HW-acceleration anyway. I have tried to force Selenium to open chrome with HW-acceleration disabled like this:

```
new DriverManager().SetUpDriver(new ChromeConfig());
                    var options = new ChromeOptions();
                    options.AddArgument("--disable-gpu");
                    driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

but the code just seems to ignore the argument and starts with acceleration enabled anyway.
Can anyone help me solve this problem? I would prefer not to change the way I take screenshots, but if that is necessary, that would be helpful as well. Thank you.

**Note 1:** I am open to solutions that are not programatical. If there is a way to instruct my users to switch of hardware acceleration themselves, I would consider it to be a valid (even if not preferred) solution.

**Note 2:** I am even willing to switch to a different browser, if you think that would help.

**Update:** I have tried similar solutions for firefox and edge and those does not seem to resolve the issue either (at least when I check settings after launching the browser via Selenium, hardware acceleration is shown as enabled).
I have also tried adding ""hardware_acceleration": false," to user-data / Preferences / Settings, but the result seems to be the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this two arguments:

```
options.AddArgument("disable-gpu");
options.AddArgument("disable-software-rasterizer");
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that does not seem to do the trick. The hardware acceleration is still enabled after launching.

Comment: Quick update - This solution seems to be working in the end (I am not sure if both lines are necessary or just the first one). The problem is that even if you start chrome using these options, the launched window claims in settings that HW-acceleration is enabled even if in reality it is not enabled.